# simplyfying a website for platform migration -- existing software or parsing script?

Tags: html, parsing, migration, html-parsing

I am migrating a website from one platform to another. Part of the requirements are to maintain URLs that may be bookmarked, which I will do with re-write rules.

Because the old system is kind of a mess, I need to take special care and make sure that all the links work. Because there are many pages, its unrealistic to do this by hand -- I'll need to automate the process. There is a main menu at the top, a submenu right below it, and a side menu -- but this could be untrue for any random page.

For the first step, what I'm looking to do is do some kind of parsing and generate a simplified version of the site. In this simplified version, I'm only worried about links.

So what I would like to do is: Parse the page and throw out most of the html, except for any link (internal or external). If a set of links all live within a particular html tag ( say, a `<ul>` that acts as a menu, or a `<div>` that acts as a content area, I would like to preserve that nesting of html tags.

Basically what I want to end up with is this:

```
index.html
<html>
  <body>
   <tag>
      <a href='page2.html'>Menu Item 1</a>
      <a href='page3.html'>Menu Item 2</a>
      <a href='page4.html'>Menu Item 3</a>
   </tag>
   <tag>
      <a href='page5.html'>SubMenu Item 4</a>
      <a href='page6.html'>SubMenu Item 5</a>
      <a href='page7.html'>SubMenu Item 6</a>
   </tag>
   <tag>
      <a href='page8.html'>Side Menu Item 1</a>
      <a href='page9.html'>Side Menu Item 2</a>
      <a href='page10.html'>Side Menu Item 3</a>
   </tag>   
   <tag>
      <a href='site.com'>Content External link</a>
      <a href='about_us.html'>Content Internal Link</a>
   </tag>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where `<tag>` could be any block-style html tag -- doesn't have to actually be the first tag that the links share.

The script/program doesn't have to be smart enough to know "This is a menu" or "This is a navigation panel"; so long as it can group links in the first html tag they all exist in, that will be good enough.

Is there a script or piece of software out there that already does this? Or will I write my own?

If I write my own, how should I do the html parsing? I've heard that regexes aren't the answer, since they can't track state and thereby cannot know about nested tag structure.

Comment: What do you use for backend code? Regex aren't the answer indeed.

Comment: I would use probably python for the scripting.

Comment: @user151847: You can check out the following page for parsing HTML with Python: http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/HTML.html